# Search for text in name range in Sheet 1and return Value in Sheet 2 using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, search, vba, find, worksheet

I have something of the following :

Sheet 1

```
(Name Range : Code)
Column A -------- Column B

School ------------ 1
College ----------- 2
University--------- 3
```

Sheet 2
Cell A1 = (Search for "College" in Name Range Code and get the Value of "2" as code. ) So value of 2 should be present in Cell A1.

Please provide excel VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub LookUpValue()
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim lookupTable As Range

    Set lookupTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Code")
    searchValue = "College"

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(searchValue, lookupTable, 2, False)

 End Sub
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`VLOOKUP`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181213/en-us) function.

Which is `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookUp` in VBA.

Comment: ok. But, I will be accessing it in 2 different worksheets. Its like searching for string in one worksheet and returning in a separate worksheet.

Comment: So, in worksheet 1, I will write a VBA to go and search string in worksheet 2, get the value from adjacent column and return to worksheet 1.

Comment: So, at the end of the day, what do you need? A formula on a sheet or a piece of code? Your use of 'VBA' is quite confusing.

Comment: Its kind of a macro. Its VBA code. Not a formula on sheet. You hit a Button, Macro runs the VBA and searches for the text.

Comment: Then use `Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("Code")` as the source table for `VLookUp` to search in.

Comment: The following code does not work :

Dim Res As String
On Error Resume Next 
Err.Clear 
Res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("College",  Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("Code"), 2, False)

Comment: Works for me. Make sure `Sheet 2` exists, and `Code` is actually defined on `Sheet 2` and has at least two columns.